# Create files that both www-data and myuser can edit

Tags: permissions, webserver

I have a directory to store invoices -

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 me www-data   49152 Sep  9 13:38 invoices
```

There are two applications that write files to this dir.

1. PHP web application

   > -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  7681 Sep  9 13:38 invoice_1.html
2. Python script

   > -rw-rw-r-- 1 me  me   8911 Sep  4 06:04 invoice_2.html

Now I want to overwrite invoice_2.html from the web application. How do I do that?

**I don't want to add `www-data` to `me` group.** I don't know how but that will make my server vulnerable to security threats.

Help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two options (both carried out as `root`):

**First**

If you're happy to have `me` be a member of the `www-data` group:

Add the user `me` to the `www-data` group:

```
# usermod -a -G www-data me
```

Set the [SetGID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) flag on the `invoices` directory:

```
# chmod g+s /<path>/<to>/invoices
```

Now, any files created in the `invoices` directory will have their group set to `www-data` (the group of the directory) due to the SetGID bit being set.  As the user `me` is in this group, then the user will have permission to write to that file.

**Second**

If you don't want the user `me` to be a member of the `www-data` group, then...

Create a new group - `invoices`.

```
# groupadd invoices
```

Add the users `me` and `www-data` to this group.

```
# usermod -a -G invoices me
# usermod -a -G invoices www-data
```

Change the group of the `invoices` directory to this new group (`invoices`).

```
# chown .invoices /<path>/<to>/invoices
```

Make sure that the group `invoices` has write permission on the directory:

```
# chmod g+w /<path>/<to>/invoices
```

Set the [SetGID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) flag on the `invoices` directory:

```
# chmod g+s /<path>/<to>/invoices
```

Now, the `invoices` directory will be owned by the `invoice` group and any files created within it will have their group set to `invoices` due to the SetGID bit being set on the directory.  Both `me` and `www-data` have write permission as they are members of the `invoices` group which has this write permission.

Comment: Both solutions are appropriate and secure. **I went with the former one**. Also to change group to www-data for files that are already created by user `me`, I did - `chgrp -R www-data </path/to/invoices>`